# How to select the second th into the thead of a table having a specific ID using CSS?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a script that renders the following table. I need to set a style on the second `th` element. (the one that contains the value "2")

```
<table id="sentbox" class="standard-table-cls">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="border-left: medium none;">1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th class="sortable">3</th>
            <th class="sortable">4</th>
            <th class="sortable">5</th>
            <th class="sortable">6</th>
            <th class="sortable">7</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>

     .................................................
     .................................................
     .................................................
</table>
```

Because the table is rendered by a script, I can't add a class or any inline CSS to `<th>2</th>`.

Is there a CSS selector that will let me target the element in question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**CSS**

```
#sentbox thead tr th:nth-of-type(2){
    \\css goes here
}
```

> `:nth-of-type()` selector matches every element that is the nth child, of a particular type, of its parent.

**DEMO**

```css
#sentbox thead tr  th:nth-of-type(2) {
   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table id="sentbox" class="standard-table-cls">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="border-left: medium none;">1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th class="sortable">3</th>
            <th class="sortable">4</th>
            <th class="sortable">5</th>
            <th class="sortable">6</th>
            <th class="sortable">7</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, with the nth-child selector

```
#sentbox thead tr th:nth-child(2) {
   ...
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/n0nrdsu9/)

Answer (score 1):

you should try like this-

```
#sentbox th:nth-child(2){your style}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#sentbox tr th:nth-child(2){

}
```